# How to convert only the first page of a PDF to a JPG with Ghostscript

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I have a large set PDF documents, many of which will be multiple pages.

I am using Ghostscript [GS] to generate a JPG thumbnail image for each PDF.

I only want one JPG per PDF, which should be an image of the **first page only**

It seems that GS allows me to do one of the following, only:

1. create an image which contains ALL pages of the PDF, or
2. create multiple images per PDF by including the characters "%d" within the output filename, where each image represents one page of the PDF

The problem with option 1 is that I only want page 1
The problem with option 2 is that I only want one file (multiple files will be generated if the PDF is multiple pages)

Given that option 2 is the closest solution to my requirements, I am writing a script to generate multiple JPGs per PDF, and then rename the first and delete the others, hence ending up with just the one file with the name that I want.

I cannot see an option in the GS help page, but can I avoid this slightly convoluted process and more easily instruct GS only to generate 1 JPG for page 1 of each PDF?

Comment: I do not know how to achieve what you want with ghostscript, however, if you are open to work with something else, pdfimage can certainly achieve what you are expecting : https://www.xpdfreader.com/pdfimages-man.html

Comment: Have a look at options `-dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1` or `-sPageList=1` (see [Parameter switches (-d and -s)](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm#Parameter_switches)).
You could get excellent results with less hassle using `pdftocairo` or `pdftoppm` instead of `gs` (install package `poppler-utils` on Debian), I've been there...
Both tools are able to output JPEG files and the options are straightforward, e.g. `pdftocairo -jpeg -singlefile -f 1 -l 1 -scale-to-x 200 -scale-to-y -1 input.pdf thumb` to generate `thumb.jpg` of page 1 with a width of 200px and proportional height.

Comment: Thanks @Freddy - I didn't have those options listed in the man page.

-sPageList=1 did the trick.

Comment: Thanks @MC68020 for that useful suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The answer (provided by [@Freddy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/332764/freddy)) was available in [the online documentation](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm#Parameter_switches):

```
-sPageList=1
```